# UIView scrolls with UICollectionView / Swift 5

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I need UIView which is on top of UICollectionView like a shadow.
When I use "addSubview" to add my View with a gradient to my CollectionView, it scrolls with my CollectionView.
When I use "bringSubviewToFront" - my View with gradient doesn't display on CollectionView.
Is any way to do it in my custom CollectionView class?

```
addSubview(topCurtainView) 
bringSubviewToFront(topCurtainView)
```

Comment: Are you using a UIViewController with a UICollectionView or are you using a UICollectionViewController?

Comment: @HangarRash Hi! No..., I use only UICollectionView in ViewControler. It works fine when I add my view with a gradient in ViewControler after UICollectionView. Can I add "topCurtainView" to my custom CollectionView class? When I do this it scrolls with my CollectionView.

Comment: Simply add the UIView to the same parent view that you added the collection view to. Then it won't scroll. A view should only scroll if it is added to the collection view.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, I know, it works, but the question is - Is any way to do it in my custom CollectionView class?

Comment: So you are asking how to add a subview to a scroll view (the collection view is a scroll view) that doesn't scroll? Why not create a custom view that contains the extra view and a collection view?

Comment: @HangarRash Do you mean to create a third view in which to reproduce everything and pass it to the controller?

Comment: Maybe. It all depends on what you are doing. Your question doesn't provide enough details to give a good answer.